# Java stored procedure's inner class not visible

Tags: java, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have a Java stored procedure in an Oracle 11g database, and it has one inner class. The procedure reads from a unix directory and uses a file filter (which is THE inner class) to filter on the files in that directory.

The stored procedure works fine from SQLPlus while logged in using the same userid as the procedure was created as.

And when this procedure is called from a C program while logged in as myself, not the same userid as mentioned above, it works fine if I comment out the file filter inner class.

But if I try to use the inner class, it can't see any files in the directory.

Note please that above I mentioned that it works fine if run from SQLPlus and it sees the files with the file filter inner class - and yes there are still files there.

What could make the inner class either not visible when run from a calling C program outside SQLPlus, or the filter not able to see the files in the directory - which ever is the problem? Thanks in advance.

~Bill

Comment: Directory permissions might now allow anyone but the correct userid to read the directory.

Comment: Hi Elliott, I appreciate your taking the time to help. The DBA and I have been all over this with permissions. Why the main class can access these files but not the innerclass I don't know. Can you help with the type of permission you suggest?